# Measuring the area of a cluster in a lattice

Tags: algorithm

I have a 2-D square lattice. At every point of the lattice i have a variable that can take two value (+1;0). At every time t in the lattice are presents disconnected clusters, of different areas, of sites that takes value +1. I have to measure the areas of every single cluster (in order to create an histogram) at every time. How can measure the areas of clusters? Is there a simple algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [connected component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) algorithm you can isolate diconnected regions and calculate their area